# Echo TAB is not working

Tags: command-line

I'm using TAB for display a block of code with commnad:

```
echo -e "192.168.1.103 \t TUNG \t 30:65:ec:1f:77:b7"
echo -e "192.168.1.107 \t LCT3VCLJN2K3MCZ \t 00:1f:c6:53:a5:36"
```

but it display not correctly in terminal:

[image]

But I want it to be display bellow:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, please help me !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need 2 tabs in the 1st line. The middle text is touching the same distance as the next tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`column`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/column) command:

```
$ { echo 192.168.1.103 TUNG 30:65:ec:1f:77:b7; echo 192.168.1.107 LCT3VCLJN2K3MCZ 00:1f:c6:53:a5:36;} | column -t
192.168.1.103  TUNG             30:65:ec:1f:77:b7
192.168.1.107  LCT3VCLJN2K3MCZ  00:1f:c6:53:a5:36
```

Comment: is this command available on other distros ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Column is a fairly standard command, yes.

Comment: @TonyTran you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking icon under vote arrows.